# Merton model d1 and probability of default

Tags: merton-model

What is the value of $d_1$ when the probability of default is 50%

I know that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
d_2 &= 0 \\
\mathcal{N}(d_2) &= 50\%\\
1- \mathcal{N}(d_2) &= \mathcal{N}(-d_2) = 50\%
\end{aligned}
$$
But I don´t know if $d_1 = 0$ or different.

Answer (score 2):

Since $d_1 = d_2 + \sigma\sqrt{\tau}$, you need to know the volatility of your asset value process. You typically estimate it from equity prices (see e.g. Hull's book).